# What programming langugage this is

Tags: html

I was working with some code that has this template inside. Although I am comfortable with it, I am just curious about the name of the language . Does anyone here know which language this is?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I bet that if you had pasted the code into a code block, Stack Overflow's engine would have told you what language it was :p

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a HTML template using the Mustache or Handlebars templating systems.

It isn't a "programming" language because it isn't Turing complete. It's a template definition which can be considered data, not programming.

Another program will load the file and instruct Mustache or Handlebars to replace each `{{something}}` with an appropriate replacement value, the resultant HTML is then output somehow (perhaps in a web-application direct to the client, a HTML email, a file on the desktop, or other possibilities).

The syntax `{{foo}}` means "this is a placeholder".

The `{{#foo}}` and `{{/foo}}` syntax means "show or hide this group if `foo` exists in the source data. So the entire `<div class="loc-name">` will not be included in any output from this template if no `location` data is provided.

See http://handlebarsjs.com/ and https://mustache.github.io/ for more information.

Comment: Thank you Dai .... Yeah the application has Handlebars